# Is SmartTarget 2011 SP3 compatible with Tridion 2013 SP1?

Tags: smarttarget

I want to know if SmartTarget 2011 SP3 is compatible with Tridion 2013 SP1? Does any one know when the latest version of SmartTarget release?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not yet a release compatible with 2013 SP1. 
It's coming soon - estimated somewhere in Q2.

Answer (score 2):

SmartTarget 2014 is underway, should be released soon.

Check here on  [Tridoin Developer summit](http://tridiondevelopersummit.com/schedule/)

Comment: Given Peter's answer, that might become SmartTarget 201**5**. ;-)

Comment: ST 2014 came out in May, and ST 2014 SP1 came out in October

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Target 2011 SP3 is indeed a compatibility release for SDL Tridion 2013 and is supported (as per best of my knowledge) on Tridion 2013 SP1 as well.

For change history, release notes and whats new in a Smart Target release you can refer following link (Required Login):

[SDL Smart Target 2011 SP3](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP3&lang=en-US#docid=concept_EC4B156565CE4B749C9980272EDBB397&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=WhatsNew2011SP3.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_EC4B156565CE4B749C9980272EDBB397)

[SDL Tridion Smart Target Releases](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP3&lang=en-US#docid=concept_9F23DED6BB3747ADAB1C84F0A29E823C&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=Intro_AboutThisRelease.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_9F23DED6BB3747ADAB1C84F0A29E823C)

Comment: ST 2011 SP3 is only compatible with SDL Tridion 2013

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this (as of November 2014)...

The following versions of Smart Target are now compatible with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1:

- SDL SmartTarget 2014
- SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1

This is documented in the [Support history: SDL Tridion](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-92B57BD0-7898-4D1A-B12A-E537CB03485C) page of the SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1 online documentation (login required).

SmartTarget 2011 SP3 is only compatible with SDL Tridion 2013 (GA).